# How do I use Routing to share data around an Angular 2 application?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a routed Angular 4 application. It has a series of nested routes like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "genes/:id", component: GenePageComponent, children: [
    { path: "mutations/:mutationType", component: MutationPageComponent },
  ]},
```

This lets me visit `/genes/123/mutations/non-coding`, so that id is 123 and mutationType is 'non-coding'.

If I inject `ActivatedRoute`, I can subscribe to the `url` or `params`, but *only for the fragment*. This means that I can only see `mutationType` in the `MutationPageComponent`.

Given that `<router-outlet>` can't emit, how can I share this `mutationType` parameter with other higher level components, for example, a sidebar, searchbar, or other top level components?

Likewise, how can I pass `params.id` from the `GenePageComponent` into the child `MutationPageComponent`?

Comment: You can get parent and child segment params from the current route, or you can use a shared service to make the params available globally.

Comment: A shared service is probably what I'll end up doing. Walking up and down child segments seems like it would be fragile. t just seems like there ought to be something built in to handle this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the parent component's route params with:

```
this.route.parent.params.subscribe(params => ....);
```

You can also do a shared service where each component updates it's value in the service for others to subscribe to.  A basic example would look like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';


@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  private _sharedDataSource = new BehaviorSubject<MyModel>(<MyModel>{});
  sharedData$ = this._sharedDataSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  updateSharedData(data: MyModel) {
     this._sharedDataSource.next(data);
  }

}
```

A `BehaviorSubject` takes a default value and ensure that the observable always emits a value.  Components can call the `updateSharedData` function to update data and subscribe to `sharedData$` to get updated value when something changes.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is one option I looked at. The thought of calling `.parent.parent.parent` sets my teeth on edge though. It's fragile. Everything will break if I move a component up or down a level. Also, I can't subscribe to the child's params from the parent or the parent's from the child, so if the parent's params change, the child won't know.

Comment: In that case, I think you need to use a shared service to share data between components.  Components at each level in the hierarchy would be required to update their param value in the shared service.  I can give an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass through router as you mentioned

```
{ path: 'form', component: FormComponent ,data :{data :'Test Data'} },
```

and your component

```
export class FormComponent {
    sub: any;
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.sub = this.route
            .data
            .subscribe(value => console.log(value));
    }
}
```

[More Info](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/12/angular-24-routing-with-simple-examples.html)

But this may not be the preferred way, `you can use parent child communication or make a service common and share data between them`. Check below references for doing that.

[Parent child communication](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/10/communicate-with-parent-and-child.html)

[Share data using service](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/09/angular-share-data-between-components.html)